# IMarkupExtension - Check property type during compilation time (xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, compilation-time

I would like to throw an exception **during compilation time** if the given parameter in the IMarkupExtension is not compatible with the type expected by me.
Can I achieve this effect?

Below I put my experiments, but I do not know where and how to check what I wrote in "TODO"

**Code (I marked todo)**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MySample
{
    public class SampleClass : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public IParameter Parameter { get; set; }
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Parameter.GetData();//TODO: throw Exception("Parameter must be of type SampleData1")
        }
    }

    public interface IParameter
    {
        string GetData();
    }
    public class SampleData1 : IParameter
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "Data1";
        }
    }
    public class SampleData2 : IParameter
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "Data2";
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mysample="clr-namespace:MySample"
             x:Class="MySample.SamplePage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <mysample:SampleData2 x:Key="SampleData2" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label>
                <Label.Text>
                    <mysample:SampleClass Parameter="{StaticResource SampleData2}" />
                </Label.Text>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

*Please note that the parameter is of the SampleData2 type, but I want to throw an exception if it is not of the SampleData1 type*.

**Resource**

```
<mysample:SampleData2 x:Key="SampleData2" />
```

**Resource usage**

```
Parameter="{StaticResource SampleData2}"
```

**Check (not necessarily in this place, but definitely during compilation)**

```
public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    return Parameter.GetData();//TODO: throw Exception("Parameter must be of type SampleData1")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is **not possible** to throw exception at compile time. The logical errors cannot be detected by the compiler, and hence they are detected only when the program is executed.

**Compile time error:**

If we do not follow the proper syntax and semantics of any programming language then the compiler throw compile time error.

For example:

1.Missing semicolon

2.writing keywords in uppercase

3.varaiable not defiend etc

**Runtime error:**

A runtime error is generated when the program is in running state. They are often termed as an exception.

For example:

1.Division by zero

2.Running out of memory

3.Dereferencing null pointer etc

You can use code below to `throw a Exception` when this function triggered and `Parameter`  is not of the `SampleData1` type.

```
 public object ProvideValue()
        {

            if (Parameter is SampleData1)
            {

                return Parameter.GetData();//TODO: throw Exception("Parameter must be of type SampleData1")
            }
            else if (Parameter is SampleData2)
            {   

                throw new Exception("Parameter must be of type SampleData1");                
            }
            return "error";
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. However, I delude myself that someone will give a surprising solution. Thank you for your comment and help.